# Problems with cleaning a data frame with ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am a novice at R, and trying to clean a data frame (MSdatanew) using ifelse. I want to change a variable E2_new so that wherever it was coded as "<0.057" it is now coded as "0.57". However, wherever it isn't coded as "<0.057", I wanted it to stay as originally coded.

```
    MSdataclean<-MSdatanew
    MSdataclean$E2_new <- ifelse(MSdataclean$E2_new=="<0.057",0.057,MSdataclean$E2_new)
```

The result from this is that the variable E2_new is altered even where it wasn't "<0.57"

```
    head(MSdatanew$E2_new)
    [1] 0.102  <0.057 2.797  11.226 5.156  10.032
    46 Levels: <0.057 >30 0.058 0.080 0.094 0.102 0.109 0.124 0.136 0.147 ... 9.711

    head(MSdataclean$E2_new)
    [1]  6.000  0.057 26.000 19.000 32.000 18.000
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace factor levels.

```
levels(MSdatanew$E2_new)[match("<0.057", levels(MSdatanew$E2_new))] <- "0.057"
```

**Example**

```
x <- gl(3,2,labels=c("<0","1","2"))
x
#[1] <0 <0 1  1  2  2 
#Levels: <0 1 2

levels(x)[match("<0",levels(x))] <- "0"
x
#[1] 0 0 1 1 2 2
#Levels: 0 1 2
```

---

If you want numerical values instead of a factor, do:

```
x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
x
#[1] 0 0 1 1 2 2
```

Similarly for your `MSdatanew$E2_new`, use:

```
MSdatanew$E2_new <- as.numeric(levels(MSdatanew$E2_new))[MSdatanew$E2_new]
```

Comment: Hey - how cool is that!! Thank you - it works great!  Do you have any thoughts as to why the ifelse approach is not working?

Comment: Both approaches worked for the problem I reported.  But another variable had a second error (values of ">30"). I may have been executing it incorrectly, but when I tried using sub() again to resolve that, the first sub() correction had already changed the ">30" into NA.  However, the levels approach allowed me to isolate each issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replace `"<"` with `""`, then convert to numeric:

```
# dummy data
MSdatanew <- data.frame(E2_new = 
                          c("0.102","<0.057","2.797","11.226","5.156","10.032"))
str(MSdatanew)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ E2_new: Factor w/ 6 levels "<0.057","0.102",..: 2 1 5 4 6 3


# sub "<" and convert to numeric
MSdatanew$E2_new_clean <- 
  as.numeric(sub("<", "", as.character(MSdatanew$E2_new), fixed = TRUE))

MSdatanew
#   E2_new E2_new_clean
# 1  0.102        0.102
# 2 <0.057        0.057
# 3  2.797        2.797
# 4 11.226       11.226
# 5  5.156        5.156
# 6 10.032       10.032
```